# Remote parameterised job passes on remote server however show fail status in upstream job - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a job running on remote server through Remote parameterised job plugin. 
My downstream job is getting triggered and also is being passed, however the status in upstream job show failure. Here is the logs

```
Triggering remote job now.
Remote Jenkins server returned empty response or invalid JSON - but we can still proceed with the remote build.
Checking parameters of #94
This job is build #[94] on the remote server.
Blocking local job until remote job completes
Remote build started!
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
Waiting for remote build to finish.
Waiting for 10 seconds until next poll.
connect timed out
Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.
Retry attempt #1 out of 5
connect timed out
Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.
Retry attempt #2 out of 5
connect timed out
Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.
Retry attempt #3 out of 5
connect timed out
Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.
Retry attempt #4 out of 5
connect timed out
Connection to remote server failed, waiting for to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt.
Retry attempt #5 out of 5
connect timed out
ERROR: Remote build failed for the following reason:
ERROR: Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

That log mean that jenkins master lost connection to remote server, what implicate that can't read slave job return. Look at logs and rest configuration - how job are executed etc...